# Искажение больших строковых переменных на ESP8266

Tags: c++, строки, esp8266

У меня возникает проблема с приёмом большого JSON с данными об участниках беседы ВКонтакте, используя метод API messages.getConversationMembers. В беседе, где 27 человек, я получаю большой JSON размером примерно 5 килобайт, вытягиваю его функцией readString в локальную переменную типа String, и очень часто после этого появляются искажения в виде нескольких пропущенных символов (а иногда вместо них может появиться отзеркаленный вопросительный знак). Фрагмент принятого с искажениями JSON выглядит вот так:

[image: Пропущенные символы в принятых данных]

В результате этого я постоянно ловлю ошибки InvalidInput (для работы с JSON использую библиотеку ArduinoJson). Заметил, что после включения ESP8266 и первого приёма большого JSON всё нормально, но на последующие разы появляются вот такие искажения. Хотя спустя несколько попыток данные все же удается вытянуть нормально. В небольшой тестовой беседе, где 4 человека и где данных приходит немного, такой проблемы нет. Вот моя функция, которую я использую для запросов к API ВКонтакте:

```
WiFiClientSecure *req;

String apiRequest(const char* link, const char* connection, String request) {
    if (!clientCreated) { // если клиент не создан,
        req = new WiFiClientSecure; // создаем его
        req->setFingerprint(vkapi_fp); // настраиваем отпечаток HTTPS SHA-1
        clientCreated = true;
        Serial.println(String("req created, heap: ") + ESP.getFreeHeap()); // выведем в терминал информацию о свободной HEAP после создания клиента.
    }
            
    if (!req->connected()) { // если подключение не установлено,
        Serial.print("connect...");
        if (!req->connect(vkapi, 443)) { // соединяемся по 443 порту и сразу же проверяем, если вдруг подключение неудачно
            Serial.println("fail!");
            return ""; // прервем функцию, вернув пустую строку
        } else Serial.println("ok");
    }
            
    Serial.print("send...");
    req->print(String("POST ") + link + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + vkapi + "\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: " + request.length() + "\r\nConnection: " + connection + "\r\n\r\n" + request); // формируем и отправляем POST запрос
    Serial.println("done");
            
    delay(500); // задержка 500 мс на всякий случай, чтобы успели придти данные
    while (req->connected()) { // пока подключение установлено,
        if (req->readStringUntil('\n') == "\r") { // вычитываем заголовки HTTP до тех пор, пока не дойдём до конца, чтобы от них избавиться (взято из примеров библиотеки ESP8266)
            Serial.println(F("headers received"));
            break;
        }
    }
    req->setTimeout(100); // выставим таймаут на ожидание следующих данных - 100 мс. Если этого не сделать, то readString() вызовет большую задержку
    String ret = req->readString(); // принимаем строку и сохраняем в переменную типа String
            
    if (connection == "close" && clientCreated) { // если было указано, что соединение должно быть закрыто и при этом клиент создан
        delete req; clientCreated = false; // уничтожим клиент для освобождения HEAP-памяти
        Serial.println(String("req deleted, heap: ") + ESP.getFreeHeap()); // выведем в терминал информацию о свободной HEAP памяти
    }
    if (debug) Serial.println("\nRET = " + ret); // если стоит режим отладки, то выведем полученную строку в терминал.
    return ret; // вернем полученную строку из функции.
}
```

Если вместо всех readString'ов воспользоваться костылём по посимвольному приёму JSON с отрезанием всего ненужного в начале:

```
String ret; bool found = false;
while (req->available()) {
    char c = req->read();
    if (debug) Serial.print(c);
    if (c == '{') found = true;
    if (found) ret += c; 
}
```

То в данных, которые были выведены в терминал посимвольно с помощью Serial.print(c), не появляется никаких искажений. В полученной строке ret всё тоже самое - тоже появляются пропуски символов.
Можно ли это как-то исправить? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать пример содержащий только заполнение строки

Comment: Вы создаете всего одного клиента, а `new WiFiClientSecure;`  , а если он создан, то больше не создаете. Не в моей сфере(не знаю как все это работает), но мне кажется  нужно хранить не один  `WiFiClientSecure `

Comment: @user7860670, вы имеете ввиду попробовать сделать программу, которая просто создает длинную строку?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, не, создание нескольких клиентов не несёт никакого смысла. Не думаю, что это как-то повлияет на сохранение принимаемых данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась переходом на массив char'ов вместо String, и соответственно использованием посимвольного чтения буфера, которое работало отлично.

```
char er[] = "error";

char* apiRequest(const char* link, const char* connection, String request) {
  if (!clientCreated) {
    req = new WiFiClientSecure;
    req->setFingerprint(vkapi_fp);
    clientCreated = true;
    Serial.println(String("req created, heap: ") + ESP.getFreeHeap());
  }

  if (!req->connected()) { // если подключение не установлено
    Serial.print("connect..."); 
    if (!req->connect(vkapi, 443)) { // подключаемся, и при неудачном подключении
      Serial.println("fail!");
      return er; // вернем указатель на массив char'ов, где записано слово "error"
    } else Serial.println("ok");
  }

  Serial.print("send...");
  req->print(String("POST ") + link + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + vkapi + "\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: " + request.length() + "\r\nConnection: " + connection + "\r\n\r\n" + request); // высылаем запрос
  Serial.println("done");

  while (!req->available()) yield(); // ждём получения данных в буфер
  uint16_t contentLength = 0; // объявляем переменную для хранения Content-Length
  while (req->available()) { // пока в буфере есть данные
    String line = req->readStringUntil('\n'); // читаем строку из буфера
    if (line.startsWith("Content-Length")) { // если это Content-Length, то
      contentLength = line.substring(16).toInt(); // читаем то, что стоит после фразы Content-Length, и сразу же преобразовываем в Int
      if (debug) Serial.printf("Length extracted: %u\n", contentLength); // если стоит режим отладки, выведем значение Content-Length в терминал.
    }

    else if (line == "\r") { // при окончании заголовков (детектируем пустую строку)
      if (debug) Serial.println(F("headers cleaned")); // при включенном режиме отладки выводим в терминал сообщение о том, что заголовки очищены
      break; // прерываем цикл чтения буфера - он нужен был только для очистки заголовков и извлечения content-length
    }
  }
  if (contentLength == 0) { // если переменная Content-Length осталась равной нулю
    Serial.println(F("Content-Length not found!")); // выведем сообщение об этом в терминал (макрос F означает, что строка будет читаться прямиком из flash-памяти esp8266, и не будет лежать в оперативной памяти)
    return er; // вернем указатель на массив char'ов, где записано слово "error"
  }
  char *reply = new char[contentLength]; // создадим в "куче" массив char'ов, размер которого равен значению Content-Length
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < contentLength; i++) { // символ за символом читаем буфер в массив char'ов
    while (!req->available()) yield(); // смысл этой строки объяснил ниже
    reply[i] = req->read(); // читаем символ из буфера в индекс i массива
  }

  if (connection == "close" && clientCreated) {
    delete req; clientCreated = false;
    Serial.println(String("\nreq deleted, heap: ") + ESP.getFreeHeap());
  }
  if (debug) Serial.printf("\nRET = %s\n", reply); // если стоит режим отладки, выведем ответ от сервера в терминал
  return reply; // вернем ответ от сервера в виде указателя на созданный массив char'ов.
}
```

После вызова функции и обработки полученного с сервера ответа, обязательно нужно удалить массив char'ов из кучи, с помощью функции delete. В функции для отправки сообщения это реализовано так:

```
bool msgSend(unsigned long peer_id, String msg, String attachment = "", bool disable_mentions = false, unsigned int forward = 0) {
  msg.replace(" ", "+"); // заменим все пробелы в запросе на плюсики, иначе сервер ВК не сможет обработать запрос
  msg.replace("\n", "%0D%0A"); // заменим символы переноса строки на HTML-символы переноса строки и возврата каретки

  unsigned long random_id = random(4294967295), random_id_secondary = random(4294967295); // создадим random_id
  String request = "peer_id=" + String(peer_id) + "&message=" + msg + "&random_id=" + String(random_id) + String(random_id_secondary); // добавляем к запросу peer_id получателя сообщения, текст сообщения, и два склеенных рандомных числа
  if (attachment != "") request += "&attachment=" + attachment; // если задано вложение, добавляем его к запросу
  if (forward) request += "&forward_messages=" + String(forward); // если задан ID сообщения, которое нужно переслать, добавим и его
  if (disable_mentions || debug) request += "&disable_mentions=1"; // если указан режим отключения упоминаний, либо включен режим отладки, добавим к запросу флаг disable_mentions (функция VK API для отключения уведомлений об упоминаниях)
  request += String("&access_token=") + token + "&v=" + api_ver; // добавим access_token и используемую версию API.

  bool msgSendOk = false;
  char* reply = apiRequest("/method/messages.send", "Keep-Alive", request); // делаем запрос

  if (reply != "error" && reply[2] == 'r') msgSendOk = true; // если функция запроса не вернула ошибку и при этом ответ начался с {"response" (проверяем это только по третьему знаку, если он равен r), ставим флаг, что всё ОК
  delete [] reply; // удаляем ответ сервера из кучи
  return msgSendOk;
}
```

В процессе реализации было замечено, что буфер при чтении в массив периодически обрывался (видимо данные с сервера читались блоками по несколько байт), в результате чего в массиве появлялась пачка отзеркаленных вопросительных знаков. Строчка `while (!req->available()) yield();` внутри цикла по чтению в массив решила эту проблему - она приостанавливает чтение буфера в массив, пока буфер пуст.